# More useful typescript dictionary type: warn accessed item could be undefined

Tags: typescript, dictionary, object, undefined, type-safety

I want to be warned when accessing a dictionary that the value may be undefined.  However I still want the type checking for when setting a value or accessing values through `Object.values()`.  Is there any type in TypeScript that has those properties, or config option that gives that error?

```
type AlwaysPresent = {[id: string]: Date }

type PotentiallyUndefined = {[id: string]: Date | undefined }


const a: AlwaysPresent = {}
// good, no error
Object.values(a).filter(date => date.getTime())
// bad, no error, we have actually no assurance there is an item in the dictionary
console.log(a["2"].getTime())
// good, correctly errors
a["1"] = undefined


const b: PotentiallyUndefined = {}
// bad, errors - this is too cautious for my use case
Object.values(b).filter(date => date.getTime())
// good, correctly errors, we have no assurance there is an item in the dictionary and this correctly warns of such an event
console.log(b["2"].getTime())
// bad, no error, this is too lax as setting undefined should not be allowed
b["1"] = undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in enabling [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) introduced in TypeScript 4.1.  This causes your original `AlwaysPresent` type to behave the way you want, at least for your example code:

```
type AlwaysPresent = {[id: string]: Date }

const a: AlwaysPresent = {}
// good, no error
Object.values(a).filter(date => date.getTime())
// good, error
console.log(a["2"].getTime())
// good, correctly errors
a["1"] = undefined
```

Note that this compiler option is not included in [the `--strict` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) (and its name does not start with `strict`) because such behavior, while desirable for some code bases, does make certain operations less convenient.  Turning it on with `--strict` would end up raising a lot of false positive warnings for existing code bases (specifically, a lot of `for` loops on arrays will start complaining about possibly `undefined` values).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNgdwIYgM4AUBOFUQHbBQC8UA3gNoCWAJgFxSrCaV4DmAuvQCJLDQC+AWABQIgMYB7PIyhJ68ZGiw58hEqSHCA9FqisJE6gBooeCVAiZMEzCIDyAIwBWEMcAB0ANyRwArjgAKJABKdwAzSjg+TADqXmgiAD4oOL53VghgABVKAFsIAODgkR09A2MLKxtxKVQJOAh3OAlWIPIAIgAmdvZ0zJz8wuLtXX1DE0krV2A4EErrTFQRJA6ARh7iKF88aggIvAhqEWPhIA)

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  Do you have any good patterns for list comprehension?  i.e. `ids = ["1", "2"];  (ids.map(id => id_to_obj[id]).filter(obj => !!obj) as Obj[]).map(/* do something */)` is painful.

Comment: Maybe write a helper function called `isDefined` that acts as a type guard? Then `filter()` will work.  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBzrpN).